# Reading file using Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)) also read blank rows. How to erase blank rows?

Tags: lambda, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a csv file with 2 rows in it. I used

```
String file1  ="C:\\sample.csv";
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)) {
```

to read the lines in the file, but looks like it also reads 3rd line as ,,,,,,
3rd line is blank. Is there a way to erase blank rows?

Comment: i have 2 rows populate in the file. When i iterating through lines in the file , it should have stopped after 2 row. But it continuses , since from 3rd row onwards it is ,,,,,, and 4th is ,,,,, and so on

Answer (score 1):

The following will ignore all empty lines:

```java
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());
```

In your case, if you want to ignore all lines that have ",,,,,,", you'd do the following:

```java
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)).filter(s -> !s.equals(",,,,,,"));
```

Alternatively, you can ignore both:

```java
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)).filter(s -> !s.equals(",,,,,,") && !s.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Instead of `s.equals("")`, you may use `s.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 2 rows in your CSV file that you're interested in and you don't want the 3rd line included, you can truncate the lines to `2` with the `limit` operation.

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)).limit(2)
```

**Update:**

It seems like you don't know the number of lines to retrieve beforehand and hence cannot use the above solution, in which case if when you say "blank" you mean lines that have ",,,,,," then as of Java-9, you can use `takeWhile`:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1))
                             .takeWhile(s -> !s.equals(",,,,,,"))
```

or if the number of commas could differ then you can do:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1))
                             .takeWhile(s -> !s.startsWith(","))
```

otherwise if when you say blank you mean *empty* then you can do:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1))
                             .takeWhile(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
```

However, if you cannot use JDK-9 for any reason then you cannot stop as soon as you find blank lines, instead, you'll need to `filter` them out like so:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1))
                             .filer(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
```

or:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1))
                             .filter(s -> !s.equals(",,,,,,"))
```

or:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1))
                             .filter(s -> !s.startsWith(","))
```

depending on what *blank lines* means to you.

Comment: But i can hard code this limit. There could be any number of lines populated. my loop needs to stops when there are no rows.

Comment: @Neha when you say "blank" do you mean empty lines or do you mean lines that have ",,,,,," and if it's the latter then would it be sufficient to filter out lines that start with "," ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(path))//Stream<String>
                .map(Optional::ofNullable) //Stream<Optional<String>>
                .flatMap(Optional::stream) //Stream<String>
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```